# 1C 8.3. Как программно завершить сеансы конкретного пользователя?

Tags: 1с

Как программно завершить сеансы конкретного пользователя в ОП и УП?
Не с помощью администрирования серверов, а именно через 1С. Например, убираем дубли сеансов (спящие сеансы).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

См. по теме следующие ссылки на Инфостарте:
https://infostart.ru/1c/tools/99006/

https://infostart.ru/1c/tools/90557/

https://infostart.ru/1c/tools/90241/

---